# What do I have to do so that the Ubuntu screen reader Orca reads a Java Swing surface

Tags: java, accessibility, orca

With Java Swing I have developed software that is screen reader compatible. The NVDA screen reader in Windows and the VoiceOver screen reader in MacOS read out the program interface.
The Orca screen reader in Ubuntu 20.04 does not read the program interface.

**Question:**

What do I have to do so that the Orca screen reader from Ubuntu 20.04 reads the Java Swing program interface?

Answer (score 0):

This used to be the [Java Access Bridge (JABG)](https://wiki.gnome.org/Attic/Java%20Access%20Bridge). But it has been superseded by [Java ATK Wrapper](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/java-atk-wrapper). ATK is a project by the GNOME / Gtk team. You can install the wrapper with `sudo apt-get install libatk-wrapper-java`. Then restart your Java program and AT-SPI integration seems to work perfectly.

For Arch Linux based distributions: The package is called [java-atk-wrapper-openjdk8](https://archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/java-atk-wrapper-openjdk8/), depending on the Java version, see the "Required by" section [here](https://archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/java-atk-wrapper-common/). Not sure why there is no `java-atk-wrapper-openjdk18` though or how to get it to work with Java 18, but at least you can switch Java versions with `archlinux-java` command.